# Internal javascript inside angularjs partial view is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Main thing here is to avoid loading of all JavaScript in index.html

Eg) I have partial view with date picker. Initialization will at the partial view side.

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('.date-pick').datePicker();
});
</script>
```

When the partial view loaded via router, the script mentioned above will not be executed. How to execute these kind of internal javascript inside angularjs partial view?

Comment: It seems that your jQuery function is inclomplete

Comment: jQuery function modified now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Erik Duindam.

Created angularjs directive which is shown below

```
// Directive for jQuery datepicker intialization
app.directive('jqueryDatepicker', function () {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
       $('.date-pick').datePicker();
    }
  }
});
```

And in partial view html file i have used created directive

```
<input name="date1" jquery-datepicker id="date1" class="date-pick"/>
```

Now the jQuery date picker is initialized in the partial view. Working great!

Answer (score 5):

Angular parses the DOM, so if you put a script tag inside, this will obviously not work. You should create a directive for your date picker and use the directive in your partial view like `<div date-picker>`. Alternatively you could add this piece of JavaScript in your controller, but I wouldn't recommend it. Creating a directive is very easy once you get used to it. Chances are that your datepicker is already available as a directive. Do a Google search on it.